# Disable SP List column using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Hope someone will be able to help me on this.

I'm looking for a way to disable (having it read only) a List column using some JSON formatting.

I know I can do it using additional calculated columns but I don't want to do this cause I have several columns and that will be too much.

Few years ago, I saw someone doing it with JSON code, something like:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

I know there's something missing in there but I don't remember what.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean by disabling list column? You don't want users to edit this field or is it link type column and you don't want your users to click on it? what is the data type of your column?

Comment: List formatting will only affect the display and has no effect on the writability (or even the display on the form) of fields

Comment: @theChrisKent: I understand what you say but i know the guy did it, he changed something in the code sample up there. and the field became read only. i just don't remember who the guy was and i don't know anyone anymore in that company.

Comment: @GaneshSanap: My columns are text. I mean having the column like "read only" . As if you were trying to type into a calculated field. i don't want the users to edit the fields. I know the downside was the fields were still editable in the form but back then, i removed them from the form.

Comment: List formatting is awesome and you can do all sorts of display things. I'm not sure where you are trying to control the editing though. If not on the form, then where?

Comment: Do you want to make this field read-only in quick edit mode?

Comment: @theChrisKent : in the list itself when you use the quick edit

Comment: @GaneshSanap : Yes ! :-)

Comment: List Formatting affects the display during Quick Edit but clicking in the cell overrides it. I am not aware of any way to make a field read only during quick edit using list formatting.

Comment: Agree with @theChrisKent, even if you add JSON formatting, if you will click on the column cell, it will allow you to edit the field.

Comment: hmm :-( I understand what you both say but I'm sure the guy did it. I just don't remember how.  Ok then, thanks anyway for your time .

Comment: When the ability to apply list formatting first rolled out to quick edit, some formats made it difficult to switch a cell to editing depending on where you clicked. You can see it a bit in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV8W84ZSxr8 so it may have been possible to hack something together that had the desired effect. Microsoft fixed this so that simply clicking within the cell removes the format. So while it's possible someone used list formatting to accomplish this, I don't believe you can do it any longer.

Comment: Hi @theChrisKent, thanks for your answer. I watched this video before creating the post. Well ok then :-( that means i'll have to create additional columns. thanks for your time ! have a great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround,you could use pnp powershell to set column read only.

```
$username = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "Password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)

Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev -Credentials $cred
 
# Get Context
$clientContext = Get-PnPContext
 
# -List: The list object or name of the list
# -Identity: The field object or name
$targetField = Get-PnPField -List "test_test" -Identity "unClickable"
 
# Make list column required
$targetField.ReadOnlyField = 1   
   
$targetField.Update()
 
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
 
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Comment: Hi @Amos_MSFT, Thanks a lot for your answer. This is great ! but... I'm working for a pretty big financial institution and our laptops are restricted for lots of things. I won't be able to do this. I finally used calculated fields to do the trick, i don't really like it but...well.  Anyway, i'll mark your solution as accepted in case it's of any help for someone else...or for me in the future. Thanks again !!